# Shoot balls at mouse location in c# GDI

Tags: c#

Hello I am trying to shoot balls to mouse location by clicking.
I really do not know if mistake is in form or in class game or if I am using wrong wrong event. Right now when I click nothing happens.

```
 public class Game
 {
     public List<Ball> Balls { get; set; } = new List<Ball>();
     public List<Base> Base { get; set; } = new List<Base>();




     public void Draw(Graphics g)
     {
         foreach (Ball item in this.Balls)
         {
             item.Draw(g);
         }




     public void Next()
     {
         foreach (Ball item in this.Balls)
         {
             item.Move();
         }
     }
```

I think there is mistake in this part but I dont know what  I am doing wrong

```
 public void Click(int x, int y)
     {
         foreach(Ball item in this.Balls)
         {
             Ball b = new Ball(this)
             {
                 X = x,
                 Y = y,
                 Vx = x / 10,
                 Vy = y / 10

             };


             this.Balls.Add(b);
         }

     }
 }



 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     private Game game;


     private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         this.game.Draw(e.Graphics);
     }

     private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         this.game.Next();
         this.pictureBox1.Refresh();
     }

     private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
     {
         this.game.Click(e.X, e.Y);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Here's a tip. Unless you are using a bitmap background in the picture box don't hook on the paint event of the picture box. Use a simpler object like a [Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.panel) or just a basic [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control) instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Click` method, you add a `new Ball(...)` for each item in `Balls`.

So if you start with 10 balls, clicking would cause 10 more balls to be added.
If you start with 0 balls, clicking would cause 0 more balls to be added.

Seems to me you should just remove the `foreach` from that method.

Comment: Yea That was it. Thanks